# Bhai Log.. I want to Find Client's Systems Physical Identity Through PHP.. is That Possible?

Tags: php, javascript, security, mac-address

Currently i am working on 1 site, its requirement is that, i have to get client systems unique identity, i am using `REMOTE_ADDR` but some time problem is that it gives me dynamic IP address sometime its common for whole organization, i want to get Uniq identity of any system from which system my site is access.. CAn i Get it through PHP or Java script, My site is in core PHP

Suggestion REquired from your side....

Comment: So the shift button is just some button you press at random times? Please put some effort in your writing. I understand that you are not a native speaker (neither am I), but capitalizing random words and not capitalizing "I"s is just annoying.

Comment: Ok i will but some time i forget to press SHIFT button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set a cookie with unique identifier on users' system so that when they revisit your website, you can identify the cookie and treat them as returning visitors, but this is not preferable if your site need a reliable way to identify users as user can clear cookies of his system when ever he wants, for general purposes, cookies are the best way to identify users. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 0):

If a company uses a dynamic IP, I don't see any way of identifying their network with a 100% certainty. The only thing I could think of is maybe using [Geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation).

For example, if you know that one company is based in Town A and uses provider X, then whenever an IP from provider X comes up, you could geolocate it and check, whether it's from the town the company is from. This isn't very error-proof, though, and if two companies from the same town use the same provider, you're screwed.

One other idea: You could fingerprint the remote system (open ports etc., check out nmap). If the fingerprint is unique enough, that might work.

Answer (score -1):

The unique identities can be the following:
username, userid, ip address
I believe there are ways to get client's mac address as well. But I do not recommend this.

What I recommend is that use a login area for the client so that you can distinguish them.

Comment: I am using ip address for admin's login panel, but some time login details are leak, and they can make changes, and ip address gives me whole organization ip,i cant get any particularly system's address - so i want any uniq identity which comes from client's computer

Comment: if your motive is to make sure no one login out of office hours, I have a solution, in fact 2. Let me know if this is what you are looking for or may be give me some more info on your requirement

Comment: im creating a bank site in php and for the data security reason, i want to get physical system identity from which system the admin login, because some how if ligin details are leak and some one else login with that details.. in the same firm and it can change into some data, thats why i want any unique identity

Comment: A bank site? You mean a complete bank website where the clients will login and do the transactions like withdraw money, make payments? If yes, than I strongly recommend that the bank will require a dedicated IP. There are tons of security measures you will need to implement. Like IP check, login history, user history, session expire etc. and many more.

Comment: No, you can't get the MAC address.

Comment: Wow.... Name that bank site. I'l probably not their use internet facilities....

Comment: Its ok itachi...dnt under estimate him..if you cant provide any useful information